# Xml serialization: serialize list of custom classes, derived from the same base class, using base class name for elements

Tags: c#, xml, list, xml-serialization, derived-class

**EDIT**

I made a mistake in my assumptions. I've answer myself to explain what was wrong and what I *really* need.

---

I have a problem to serialize a list of different custom classes. Each of them inherit from the same base class, and the Xml file should show elements with base class name.

This is how I want my Xml file looks like:

```
<TestDataMap>
    <DataMap>
        <Item Key="BoolStatus">True</Item>
        <Item Key="IntStatus">77</Item>
    </DataMap>
</TestDataMap>
```

My actual code is composed by a base class:

```
    public class BaseItem
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Key")]
        public string Key { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

and multiple custom classes, for example:

```
    [XmlType("ItemBool")]
    public class ItemBool : BaseItem
    {
        public ItemBool()
        {
            base.Key = string.Empty;
            ValueBool = false;
        }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public bool ValueBool
        {
            get { return bool.Parse(base.Value); }
            set { base.Value = value.ToString(); }
        }
    }

    [XmlType("ItemInt")]
    public class ItemInt : BaseItem
    {
        public ItemInt()
        {
            base.Key = string.Empty;
            ValueInt = int.MinValue;
        }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public int ValueInt
        {
            get { return int.Parse(base.Value); }
            set { base.Value = value.ToString(); }
        }
    }
```

I need to serialize all of these custom classes as a list of my base class, so I've done the following:

```
    [XmlRoot("TestDataMap")]
    public class TestDataMap
    {
        public TestDataMap()
        {
            DataMap = new List<BaseItem>();
        }

        // If I use the following I've got serialization exception...
        //[XmlArrayItem("Item", typeof(ItemBool))]
        //[XmlArrayItem("Item", typeof(ItemInt))]
        [XmlArray("DataMap")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Item", typeof(BaseItem))]
        public List<BaseItem> DataMap { get; set; }
    }
```

To test the serialization I'm using a button event:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestDataMap testDataMap = new TestDataMap();
        ItemBool itemBool = new ItemBool() { Key = "BoolStatus", ValueBool = true };
        ItemInt itemInt = new ItemInt() { Key = "IntStatus", ValueInt = 77 };
        testDataMap.DataMap.Add(itemBool);
        testDataMap.DataMap.Add(itemInt);

        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\TempTest.xml");
        Type[] dataMapTypes = new Type[] { typeof(ItemBool), typeof(ItemInt) };
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestDataMap), dataMapTypes);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, testDataMap);
        writer.Close();
    }
```

But I obtain an output like this:

```
<TestDataMap>
    <DataMap>
        <Item Key="BoolStatus" xsi:type="ItemBool">True</Item>
        <Item Key="IntStatus" xsi:type="ItemInt">77</Item>
    </DataMap>
</TestDataMap>
```

that contains `xsi:type` information that I don't want to show...
What's wrong with my code? Any suggestions about what I have to change to obtain exactly the Xml structure I posted at the begin of the question?

Comment: Well, removing `[XmlType("ItemBool")]` would remove `xsi:type="ItemBool"`; but that also means that it wouldn't deserialize without some work.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud - I've tried to remove `[XmlType("ItemBool")]` as you suggested, but the `xsi:type` part is still there. Are there some _implicit_ attributes I need to make _explicit_?

Answer (score 0):

When I asked this question I was too focus on the *aesthetical* result of the output xml file, instead of caring about the important point: xml serialization of custom classes and subsequent deserialization.
Even if I will be able to obtain *exactly* the xml elements as I originally posted, then I will have problems during deserialization: how can the deserializer knows, from a list of generic `<Item>` elements, which one is `<ItemBool>` and which one is `<ItemInt>`, without any other detail?

Thinking about this, I understand that what I've asked is not what I need, nor is the correct way to do xml serialization.

So I've changed the `TestDataMap` class I posted above to the following:

```
[XmlRoot("TestDataMap")]
public class TestDataMap
{
    public TestDataMap()
    {
        DataMap = new List<BaseItem>();
    }

    [XmlArray("DataMap")]
    [XmlArrayItem("ItemBool", typeof("ItemBool"))]
    [XmlArrayItem("ItemInt", typeof("ItemInt"))]
    public List<BaseItem> DataMap { get; set; }
}
```

To obtain this xml output:

```
<TestDataMap>
    <DataMap>
        <ItemBool Key="BoolStatus">True</ItemBool>
        <ItemInt Key="IntStatus">77</ItemInt>
    </DataMap>
</TestDataMap>
```

In this way, it's clear for the deserializer how it has to deserialize each type of `<Item>` element.